# Woocommerce single product summary hook priority

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have an issue with Woocommerce. I'm trying to change the order in which a single product summary is displayed. I know already it is done by removing/adding hooks and giving new priority numbers in content-single-product.php. The default php file has them ordered exactly the way I want

```
<?php
/**
* woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
* @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

For some reason the page displays the price in the first place, then the short description, then the title and add to cart button
(see screenshot below)

[image: see screenshot]

I have digged deep into the woocommerce php files to see where it could possibly be overwritten to show price in the first place but without success.

I would appreciate any hints, tips, suggestions how to change the order of the summary or why is this happening...

Comment: part of the html for this section may help

Comment: Hi DanielSVK, thanks for the comment but I don't understand what you mean. Do you want me to give part of the html or do you have some that might help?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, that look at the part of your html, responsible for the product summary, can be useful...

Comment: @DanijelSVK the thing with woocommerce is that it's built with all these php files so there isn't really a single html file. Strange thing is when I try to rearrange the items using inspect in Chrome, even if I place the price code snippet below the title code snippet or the title above the price it won't budge.

Comment: yup, I would like to see the html output from Chrome inspect... just the excerpt for the single product summary... After that I will see if the problem is on the php side or css side...

Comment: please remove the hooks for the price and at the place of price hook add excerpt hook. see [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206655/woocommerce-change-display-order-of-product-short-description-and-price)

Comment: @SunilDora Hi Sunil and thank you for the comment. I tried doing that a few times but no success. I understand how to switch positions of different items on the page using remove_action and add_action with new priorities. What I don't understand is why is the title of my product below the price even though the wc/includes/wc-template-hooks.php has title with a priority of 5 and price a priority of 10.

Comment: @DanijelSVK So I'm not sure if you need the whole html of that specific product page (I've copied it and it's long so I don't want to insert the whole thing in here) but maybe it will be easier if you check it yourself. Here's the link to the product page [https://guapahome.com/en/product/bricasso-recycle-en/]

Comment: can u plz share your site link. So, I may check. If it is a CSS issue.

Comment: Sure Sunil,here it is [https://guapahome.com/en/]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the hook priorities are set correctly in **woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php**, then the problem must be with your theme.

I found that your theme's CSS has used the order property to set a different display order for the product title:

```
.woocommerce .single-product div.product .product_title,
.woocommerce.single-product div.product .product_title {
margin-bottom: 20px;
-moz-order: 2;
-ms-flex-order: 2;
order:2
}
```

Removing the order properties from your style sheet should solve your problems.